Error creating payment intent: StripeAuthenticationError
As you can imagine I'm currently setting up the payment API with using Stripe. Problem is, I've never done such thing before and am following the docs pretty much one by one.
This the payment.jsx code:
import React from "react";
import CheckoutForm from "./CheckoutForm";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import useCart from "../../hooks/useCart";

const stripePromise = loadStripe(import.meta.env.VITE_Stripe_PK);
const Payment = () => {
    const [cart] = useCart();
    console.log(cart);
    // calculate the checkout prices
    const cartTotal = cart.reduce((sum,item)=> sum + item.price ,0)
    const totalPrice = parseFloat(cartTotal.toFixed(2));


  return (
    <div className="max-w-screen-2xl container mx-auto xl:px-24 px-4 py-28">
      <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
        <CheckoutForm price={totalPrice} cart={cart} />
      </Elements>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Payment;

Create CheckOut Code
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { FaPaypal } from "react-icons/fa";
import useAxiosSecure from "../../hooks/useAxiosSecure";
import useAuth from "../../hooks/useAuth";

const CheckoutForm = ({ price, cart }) => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  const axiosSecure = useAxiosSecure();
  const { user } = useAuth();

  const [cardError, setCardError] = useState("");
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof price !== "number" || price < 1) {
      console.log("Price is not a number or less than 1");
      return;
    }
    axiosSecure.post(`/create-payment-intent`, { price }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data.clientSecret);
      setClientSecret(res.data.clientSecret);
    });
  }, [price, axiosSecure]);
  


  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      // Stripe.js has not loaded yet. Make sure to disable
      // form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.
      return;
    }
    // create a card element
    const card = elements.getElement(CardElement);
  
    if (card == null) {
      return;
    }
  
    // Use your card Element with other Stripe.js APIs
    const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: 'card',
      card,
    });
  
    if (error) {
      console.log("[error]", error);
      setCardError(error.message);
    } else {
      setCardError("success!");
      console.log("[PaymentMethod]", paymentMethod);
    }
  
    // Correct the usage of clientSecret
    const { paymentIntent, error:confirmError } =
      await stripe.confirmCardPayment(
        `${clientSecret}_secret`,  // Corrected usage of clientSecret
        {
          payment_method: {
            card: card,
            billing_details: {
              name: user?.displayName || "anonymous",
              email: user?.email || "unknown",
            },
          },
        }
      );
    if (confirmError) {
      console.log(confirmError);
    }
    console.log(paymentIntent);
    if (paymentIntent.status === "succeeded") {
        console.log(paymentIntent.id);
        setCardError(`Your transactionId is${paymentIntent.id} `)
        // payment info data
        const paymentInfo ={
            email: user.email,
            transitionId:paymentIntent.id,
            price,
            quantity: cart.length,
            status:"Order pending",
            itemName: cart.map(item => item.name),
            cartItems: cart.map(item => item._id),
            menuItem: cart.map(item => item.menuItem)
        }
        console.log(paymentInfo);
        // send information to backend
        axiosSecure.post('/payments',paymentInfo)
        .then( res =>{
            console.log(res.data);
        })
    }
  };
  

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col sm:flex-row justify-start items-start gap-8">
      {/*left side */}
      <div className="md:w-1/2 w-full space-y-3 ">
        <h4 className="text-lg font-semibold">Order Summary</h4>
        <p>Total Price: ${price}</p>
        <p>Number of Items: {cart.length}</p>
      </div>
      {/* right side*/}
      <div className="md:w-1/3 w-full space-y-3 card shrink-0 max-w-sm shadow-2xl bg-base-100 px-4 py-8">
        <h4 className="text-lg font-semibold">Process Your Payment!</h4>
        <h5 className="font-medium">Credit/Debit Card</h5>
        {/* Stripe Form */}
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <CardElement
            options={{
              style: {
                base: {
                  fontSize: "16px",
                  color: "#424770",
                  "::placeholder": {
                    color: "#aab7c4",
                  },
                },
                invalid: {
                  color: "#9e2146",
                },
              },
            }}
          />
          <button
            type="submit"
            disabled={!stripe}
            className="btn btn-sm mt-5 btn-primary w-full text-white"
          >
            Pay
          </button>
        </form>
        {cardError ? (
          <p className="text-red text-center italic text-xs">{cardError}</p>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}

        {/* Paypal */}
        <div className="mt-5 text-center">
          <hr />
          <button
            type="submit"
            disabled={!stripe}
            className="btn btn-sm mt-5 bg-orange-500 text-white"
          >
            <FaPaypal /> Pay With Paypal
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CheckoutForm;

and ServerSide Code
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const port = process.env.PORT || 6001;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
require("dotenv").config();

// middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

//mongodb configuration using mongoose
mongoose
  .connect(
    `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@demo-foodi-client.xsy4pne.mongodb.net/demo-foodi-client?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
  )
  .then(console.log("MongoDB Connected Successfully"))
  .catch((error) => console.log("Error connecting to MongoDB", error));

// jwt authentication
app.post("/jwt", async (req, res) => {
  const user = req.body;
  const token = jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: "1hr",
  });
  res.send({ token });
});

//   import routes here
const menuRoutes = require("./api/routes/menuRoutes");
const cartRoutes = require("./api/routes/cartRoutes");
const userRoutes = require("./api/routes/userRoutes");
const paymentRoutes = require("./api/routes/paymentRoutes");
app.use("/menu", menuRoutes);
app.use("/carts", cartRoutes);
app.use("/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/payments", paymentRoutes);

app.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { price } = req.body;
    const amount = price * 100; // Convert price to cents

    // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: amount,
      currency: "usd",
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
    });

    res.send({ clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating payment intent:", error);
    res.status(500).send({ error: "Failed to create payment intent" });
  }
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello Foodi Client Server!");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});

The image of error:


Can you click on the error and expand the full error details? What does it say?

link
i got clean screenshot of error for you

i solved the Error Just i generated a new Secret Strip Key
And  unused process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY and puted the key
and it works
but the key shown in console so it's not secure
but if anyone can help me to make it work with process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
it will be nice <3
